# Putting values into an inner Map

Tags: java, spring, collections

I have a ConcurrentHashMap that looks like this:

```
private Map<String,Map<String,Set<PublicKey>>> instancePairs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

And a method that is supposed to fill this hashmap up.

But i can't figure out how to put the values in the map

Currently i have:

```
instancePairs.putIfAbsent(inMemoryInstance.getUsername(), inMemoryInstance.getId() , publicKeySet);
```

Intellij Idea is giving me this error:

[image: picture]

Comment: You should get the inner map by key first, create it if it is not there, and only after that put your values in the inner map.

Comment: `putIfAbsent()` expects 2 parameters, but you are giving it three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by "DDovzhenko", you'd need to do something along the following lines.

```
//Get the map containing the ID as keys, if it doesn't exist, then create one.
Map mapValuesForName = instancePairs.getOrDefault(inMemoryInstance.getUsername(), new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Set<PublicKey>>());

//Put the publicKeySet based on the Id.
mapValuesForName.putIfAbsent(inMemoryInstance.getId(), publicKeySet);

//Store the potentially changed/new value back in original map.
instancePairs.put(mapValuesForName);
```